# Dynamodb query not working

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want perform `query` on multiple columns in `dynamodb` 
I want to search on 4 fields 
`rule0` which is unique hence `hash key`, 
`which_rule` is `Global Index`, 
`rule1` is `Global Index`, 
`rule2` is `Global Index`,

I searching for `rule0` first then `rule1` then `rule2`
I am using following function to match `rule1` cause match not found with `rule0`

```
function dynamoQueryRule1(rule0, rule1, funcQ) {
    which_rule = "rule1";
    var q = {
        "KeyConditions": {
            "rule0": {
                "ComparisonOperator": "EQ", 
                "AttributeValueList": [{
                        "S": rule0
                    }]
            }
        },
        "TableName": "tbl_scripts" + table_prefix, 
        "AttributesToGet": ['id'],
        "ConditionalOperator": "AND",
        "QueryFilter": {

                    "which_rule": {
                        "ComparisonOperator": "EQ",
                        "AttributeValueList": [{
                                "S": which_rule
                            }]
                    },
                    "rule1": {
                        "ComparisonOperator": "EQ",
                        "AttributeValueList": [{
                                "S": rule1
                            }]
                    }
        }
    };
    var params = {
        TableName: this.options.tbl_name
    };
```

But this function is never gets results for `rule1`. Even I have already created those rules in `dymamo table`. 
To check dynamo data, I have checked with `scan` its working fine but `scan` having 1mb limitation and not perfect usecase for my problem.
Please help me to find bug in `query` format.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your response object has [LastEvaluatedKey] != null.

If the [LastEvaluatedKey] is set then it means you did not query the entire dataset yet (again because of the 1M limit).  So you would need to call query again setting the ExclusiveStartKey in the query = the LastEvaluatedKey from the previous response. (appending all the results together)

This similar question shows the syntax for how to do this in node.js:
 [Recursive Fetch All Items In DynamoDB Query using Node JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25241864/recursive-fetch-all-items-in-dynamodb-using-node-js)